# What happens if return is not used in a Recursive Return Function?

Tags: c, recursion

```
#include <stdio.h>
int lcm(int ,int );
int main()
{
   int a,b,f;
   printf("Enter the numbers:");
   scanf("%d %d",&a,&b);
   f=lcm(a,b);
   printf("LCM of %d and %d : %d",a,b,f);
   return 0;
}

int lcm(int a,int b)
{
    static int x=1;
    if(x%a==0 && x%b==0)
        return x;
    x++;
    lcm(a,b);
}
```

Now, this code isn't giving any error ... and giving me correct answer but how the value is being return to main function without the return keyboard in lcm function 
 "  lcm(a,b); " !! Please Explain !!

Comment: Undefined behavior happens.

Comment: Unfortunately returned value is used in main. The behavior is defined only if both a and b are 1.

Comment: "Now, this code isn't giving any error" - No, but in C warnings shall be taken equally serious!

Comment: Note that your code is useless after the first top-level call to `lcm()`.  You have no way to reset `x` to `1` to restart the process.  So, the whole concept is fatally flawed, quite apart from the undefined behaviour you're using.

Answer (score 1):

> Now, this code isn't giving any error ... and giving me correct answer but how the value is being return to main function without the return keyboard in lcm function lcm(a,b);

C language allows incorrect code and lets you shoot yourself in the foot. This is called [undefined behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). Your code exhibits undfined behaviour for any arguments except (1,1). When you pass (1,1) the first return is triggered for the very first time.

You should read [What Every C Programmer Should Know About Undefined Behavior](http://blog.llvm.org/2011/05/what-every-c-programmer-should-know.html) for some detailed explanation with examples.

Having said that, it's not undefined behaviour to ignore the return value per se. It's *only* undefined the caller uses the return value from the function. 
For example, your already ignores the return values of `scanf()` and `printf()` functions in your code yet they are valid. Although, you *should* check the return value of `scanf()` to if the scanning was successful! On a relevant note, [`scanf()` use is discouraged in C](http://c-faq.com/stdio/scanfprobs.html) as it's error prone.

But in your code, you do use the return value (`f=lcm(a,b);`). Hence, there's undefined behaviour (with the one above stated exception).

But if you were to write the call to `lcm()` main as:

```
 scanf("%d %d",&a,&b);
 lcm(a,b);
 ...
```

then there won't be any undefined behaviour (although it won't be useful in your program).

Comment: " It's only undefined the caller uses the return value from the function. " - I believe calling a non-void function, not returning value *is* a UB by itself, regardless of ignoring the return value. Let me look for a reference..

Comment: So yeah. It is OK if the value is ignored. There is a rather blurry paragraph in the [standard](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.9.1p12): *If the } that terminates a function is reached, and the value of the function call is used by the caller, the behavior is undefined.* Blurry is because it is not conditioned by the existence of the `return` statement..

Comment: @EugeneSh. I don't see what's blurry there. 6.9.1,12 is quite clear. *"} that terminates a function is reached"* (C++ uses the term *"Flowing off the end of a function"*) means there's no return statement in the function through which it returns (or the function doesn't return via any *return* statements if they present).

Comment: So it is considered that the `}` is never reached, if there is a `return` before it? OK then..